# Autorun script that create text file

Tags: file, text, autorun, usb-drive

For safety and precaution I created a file with information about me, so in a case I lose my pendrive, the person knows where to contact me. But my friends always alter the contents of the file or its name.

It´s possible to create an autorun.inf file that always generate a text file (.txt) into pendrive with some information about the owner of this pendrive?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a script to check the file on load, on when some unit process occurs. Is it a real drive? Maybe you can run the equiv of an autoexec command.